# Is there an algorithm for converting a polygon to a square image?

Tags: algorithm, image-processing

I have written code that can detect the area of a puzzle with my webcam and would like to transform it to a square image of the puzzle area for further analysis:

[image: puzzle area]

So I want to map it to a 640x480 area.  My first thought is to do something like this pseudocode, but I think there is probably a well defined algorithm for it I haven't been able to find...

```
  // x, y is from 0,0 to 639,479 in the target image
  let topX = B.x - A.x;
  let topY = B.y - A.y;
  let bottomX = C.x - D.x;
  let bottomY = C.y - D.y;

  pointAt(x, y) {
    let frac = x / 639; // how far along line from A to B or D to C

    // point along top AB line for x position
    let top = { x: A.x + (frac * topX), y: A.y + (frac * topY) };

    // point along bottom CD line for x position
    let bottom = { x: D.x + (frac * bottomX), y: D.y + (frac * bottomY) };

    // now get point along line from top to bottom
    let dx = bottom.x - top.x;
    let dy = bottom.y - top.y;
    frac = y / 479;
    return { x: top.x + (frac * dx), y: top.y + (frac * dy) };
  }
```

***Update***

I ended up using my pseudocode so far and it works pretty good and is fast enough for my needs, about 20ms to transform the image on my laptop: [*code*](https://github.com/JasonGoemaat/puzzles/blob/bc9fe81d664ac3ca2ace21e9a48fc4cedc46d274/src/app/train/analyzer.ts#L218) (pardon the mess, doing a lot of experimenting).  Overlay on original image:

[image]

Comment: I'm surprised you can do something this complex, but can't do something as easy as a skew transformation. In any event, what language do you need this in?

Comment: a simple solution could be: find the angle using the two points A, B and then just rotate the image

Comment: @AlbertRenshaw I'm doing it in typescript/javascript since I want to do it in a simple web page, but could figure out the algorithm from other languages so I didn't want it add the tag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Perspective Transformation Algorithm in [OpenCV](https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2014/08/25/4-point-opencv-getperspective-transform-example/) and [BoofCV](https://boofcv.org/index.php?title=Example_Remove_Perspective_Distortion). In case, you are planning to write your own code for this, I would recommend reading [this](http://sudokuvision.blogspot.com/2011/01/step-5-perspective-transformation.html) blog.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for the links, they helped me find the terms I was looking for, "perspective transformation' seems like a good one.